# using onTouch and onCreateContextMenu at the same time

Tags: android

I am looking to capture the coordinates of the users touch event (For this I implemented the `onTouch` method), but I also want to display a context menu when the user touches the screen.

When both the `onTouch` and `onCreateContextMenu` methods are used, every touch event is sent to the `onTouch` method. The `onCreateContextMenu` method is never called. I guess this is expected. I then tried manually displaying the context menu by calling `openContextMenu(v)` in the `onTouch` method, this works, but the menu doesn't disappear from the screen after the `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` call. So how can I make this work?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record_match);
    myCourtView = new MyImageView(getApplicationContext());
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    ll.addView(myCourtView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    registerForContextMenu(myCourtView);
    myCourtView.requestFocus();
    myCourtView.setOnTouchListener(this);

}// End OnCreate


    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      //do something when user interacts with the court view
      myCourtView.processEvent(event);
      openContextMenu(v);
      myCourtView.invalidate();
      return true;
    }//End OnClickListener

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.shot_entry_menu, menu);
}//End onCreateContextMenu

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.player_1:
    //do something
    return true;
  case R.id.player_2:
    //do something else
    return true;
  }
  return true;
}//End onContextItemSelected
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return false in onTouch:

True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution work:

```
myCourtView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev)
        {});
```

Rest is the same

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in  public boolean onTouch   after return true;  registerForContextMenu(this.getListView());